# Keycloak REST API 401 when using custom client with service account

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

we want to access the Keycloak (Version 10) REST API from one of our backend services. To authenticate, we have setup the followings:

- new clients within our realm
- enabled service account for that client
- assigned all [1] roles of “realm-management” to the services account

**Accessing the API, e.g. fetching a selected user always results in a 401 response.**

Steps to make the requests are:

1. Retrieve access_token from https://my-keycloak.com/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token using `grant_type=client_credentials` + Client ID + Client Secret
2. Fetch user from https://my-keycloak.com/auth/realms/my-realm/users/some-user-id-4711
   using the `Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN` with the Token from step 1.

My Question: Is it even possible to use a custom client or do we have to stick to login via admin-cli? How would we need to configure the custom client, to grant access to the REST API.

Thanks,
Martin

[1] Simply setting all roles for the sake of testing, regardless that we only want to read data in the end.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to use a custom client to be able to call the rest API like you would with the admin-cli?

Comment: I've been having the same problem and getting the feeling that it is not possible to manage a users account without using the admin account, which is kind of frustrating